# Putting Bayes Theorem to work

Tags: discrete-mathematics, bayesian

The question asks:

> The instructor of a discrete mathematics class gave two
>   tests. Twenty-five percent of the students received an A on
>   the first test and 15% of the students received A’s on both
>   tests. What percent of the students who received A’s on the
>   first test also received A’s on the second test?

I'm still learning how to properly apply Bayes Theorem to questions like this. Bayes Theorem says:

$$ P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A) \, P(A)}{P(B)} $$

For this problem, the probability of getting an A on the first exam (lets call that *F*) is .25:

$P\left(F\right)=.25$

(This would mean that complement of F, or the chance of not getting an A on the first exam, is $P\left(F^c\right)=1-.25\:=\:.75$, right? Not sure if this is pertinent to the question though).

While the probability of getting an A on both the first and second exam (let's call getting an A on the second exam *S*). I think this would be represented as:

$P\left(F\cap S\right)=.15$

In the end, we are attempting to compute:

$$ P(F \mid S) = \frac{P(S \mid F) \, P(F)}{P(S)} $$

...I think.

I'm struggling to figure out how to find $P\left(S\right)$ and $ P(S \mid F) $ from the above details however. Any advice for solving this?

Comment: You are over thinking this.  Say there were $100$ students.  Then $25$ got an $A$ on the first test, and $15$ got an $A$ on both.  Therefore the answer is $\frac {15}{25}$.

Comment: I see...because 15 students out of the 25 who got As on the first exam got As on the second exam. Wow, I guess I was expecting something much more complex, thank you!